# Bug? Stargazer fails to properly display fixed effects/factor labels with "omit" options?

Tags: r, stargazer

When I generate a table in `stargazer` and omit fixed effects, then specify the `omit.labels` option, stargazer (version 5.2.2) shows "No" for every column. Here's an example:

```
library(stargazer)

# generate example data
set.seed(1)
list_of_states <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5)
df <- data.frame("state" = list_of_states, "y" = runif(25),
    "x1" = runif(25), "x2" = runif(25))

# OLS without fixed effects
ols.1 <- glm(y ~ x1, data = df)
ols.2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)

# OLS with fixed effects
fe.1 <- glm(y ~ x1 + factor(state), data = df)
fe.2 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(state), data = df)

stargazer(ols.1, ols.2, fe.1, fe.2,
  type = "text",
  align = TRUE,
  omit = c("state"),
  omit.labels = c("State FE"))
```

This outputs

```
==================================================
                        Dependent variable:       
                  --------------------------------
                                 y                
                    (1)      (2)     (3)     (4)  
--------------------------------------------------
x1                 0.088    0.098   0.151   0.157 
                  (0.241)  (0.264) (0.263) (0.283)

x2                          0.028           0.022 
                           (0.270)         (0.287)

Constant          0.485*** 0.467*  0.466**  0.452 
                  (0.142)  (0.227) (0.215) (0.280)

--------------------------------------------------
State FE             No      No      No      No   
--------------------------------------------------
Observations         25      25      25      25   
Log Likelihood     -5.321  -5.315  -3.528  -3.524 
Akaike Inf. Crit.  14.642  16.630  19.056  21.048 
==================================================
Note:                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

The labels in the "State FE" row should say "Yes" in the last two columns. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that it's a bug.  It appears that the intent of the code is to create a matrix that looks something like

```
cbind(names(coef(ols.1)), names(coef(fe.1)))
#      [,1]          [,2]            
# [1,] "(Intercept)" "(Intercept)"   
# [2,] "x1"          "x1"            
# [3,] "(Intercept)" "factor(state)2"
# [4,] "x1"          "factor(state)3"
# [5,] "(Intercept)" "factor(state)4"
# [6,] "x1"          "factor(state)5"
```

and then check each column for the `omit` regex.  However, what actually happens is something like

```
cbind(cbind(NULL, names(coef(ols.1))), names(coef(fe.1)))
#      [,1]          [,2]         
# [1,] "(Intercept)" "(Intercept)"
# [2,] "x1"          "x1"
```

which results in the `omit` term not being found.  This happens because, from `?cbind`

> When the arguments consist of a mix of matrices and vectors the number of columns (rows) of the result is determined by the number of columns (rows) of the matrix arguments. Any vectors have their values recycled or subsetted to achieve this length.