# Omit factor variables in `huxreg`

Tags: r, reporting

I am running a regression in R with a lot of time and location fixed effects. I try to output a nice summary table into Latex. I switched from `stargazer` package to `huxtable` because `stargazer` does not behave consistently when omitting fixed effects (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026337/bug-stargazer-fails-to-properly-display-fixed-effects-factor-labels-with-omit)).

Here is a simple example:

```
library(huxtable)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
reg2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + factor(gear) + factor(carb), data = mtcars)
huxreg(reg1, reg2)
```

The output of `huxreg` is:

```
> huxreg(reg1, reg2) 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                        (1)              (2)        
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  (Intercept)          29.600 ***       25.533 ***  
                       (1.230)          (2.996)     
  disp                 -0.041 ***       -0.018      
                       (0.005)          (0.011)     
  factor(gear)4                          3.988      
                                        (2.495)     
  factor(gear)5                          5.391 *    
                                        (2.591)     
  factor(carb)2                         -1.979      
                                        (1.667)     
  factor(carb)3                         -4.161      
                                        (2.131)     
  factor(carb)4                         -6.199 *    
                                        (2.221)     
  factor(carb)6                         -8.557 *    
                                        (3.653)     
  factor(carb)8                        -10.389 *    
                                        (4.268)     
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  N                    32               32          
  R2                    0.718            0.828      
  logLik              -82.105          -74.186      
  AIC                 170.209          168.372      
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.           

Column names: names, model1, model2
```

Here is the desired output:

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                        (1)              (2)        
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  (Intercept)          29.600 ***       25.533 ***  
                       (1.230)          (2.996)     
  disp                 -0.041 ***       -0.018      
                       (0.005)          (0.011) 
                 ───────────────────────────────────    
  Gear FE                No               Yes
  Carb FE                No               Yes
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  N                    32               32          
  R2                    0.718            0.828      
  logLik              -82.105          -74.186      
  AIC                 170.209          168.372      
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.           

Column names: names, model1, model2
```

I know I could simply edit the huxtable using `add_rows()`, but I am looking for a more robust solution that would allow to find rownames using regular expressions (like stargazer's `omit.labels` option).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote the answer myself, using [this](https://statsf18.classes.andrewheiss.com/class/08-class/) as inspiration.

The function `check_factors()` determines if the particular variables are present in the model, and then `sapply()` is used to create the rows that are added in the table. This is not *fully* automatic, though, since I still have to check if all the variables listed for `omit_coef` were later tested by `check_factors()`. It is possible to omit a variable and then forget to add a corresponding row.

```
library(huxtable)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
reg2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + factor(gear) + factor(carb), data = mtcars)
huxreg(reg1, reg2) 

gear_factors <- tidy(reg2) %>%
  filter(str_detect(term, "factor\\(gear\\)")) %>% ## in R, you have to escape the escape, hence \\
  pull(term)

carb_factors <- tidy(reg2) %>%
  filter(str_detect(term, "factor\\(carb\\)")) %>% 
  pull(term)

check_factors <- function(model, factors) {
  return(all(factors %in% (tidy(model) %>% pull(term))))
}

models_report <- list(reg1 , reg2)
huxreg(models_report,
       omit_coefs = c(gear_factors, carb_factors)) %>%
  # add the rows with with True/false returned by check_factors() replased with "Yes"/"No"
  add_rows(rbind(c("Gear FE", 
                   ifelse(sapply(models_report, 
                                 check_factors, 
                                 factors=gear_factors), 
                          "Yes", "No")), 
                 c("Carb FE", 
                   ifelse(sapply(models_report, 
                                 check_factors, 
                                 factors=carb_factors), 
                          "Yes", "No"))),
                 copy_cell_props = FALSE, # this will prevent horizontal lines from appearing
           after = nrow(.) - 5)
```

This produces the following table:

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                        (1)              (2)        
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  (Intercept)          29.600 ***       25.533 ***  
                       (1.230)          (2.996)     
  disp                 -0.041 ***       -0.018      
                       (0.005)          (0.011)     
                 ───────────────────────────────────
  Gear FE          No               Yes             
  Carb FE          No               Yes             
  N                    32               32          
  R2                    0.718            0.828      
  logLik              -82.105          -74.186      
  AIC                 170.209          168.372      
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.           

Column names: names, model1, model2
```

Comment: If you want the No and Yes also to be centered, just pipe in
  set_align(rownumber1:rownumber2, everywhere, "center")  |>